# Github API error - { "message": "Not Found", "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3" } making repo in cURL terminal

Tags: curl, github, github-api

api is v3, the reason that I am trying to make a tool so that when you input your username and password for github and the repo name and description, it will initialize the repo and give you the url. My input is this -

```
curl -u {myuser}:{mypassword} -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"api-test","description":"made with github api","homepage": "https://github.com","private":true}' POST https://api.github.com/users/{myuser}/repos
```

I get the response

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

. The docs say this : Creates a new repository for the authenticated user. POST /user/repos. https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create. I am very new to github-api, and thankful for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [curl tutorial](https://gist.github.com/joyrexus/85bf6b02979d8a7b0308) for your GitHub API calls

> ### POST
>
> Use the `--request` (`-X`) flag along with `--data` (`-d`) to `POST` data

```
curl --user "caspyin" --request POST --data '{"description":"Created via API","public":"true","files":{"file1.txt":{"content":"Demo"}}' https://api.github.com/gists

curl --user "caspyin" -X POST --data '{"description":"Created via API","public":"true","files":{"file1.txt":{"content":"Demo"}}' https://api.github.com/gists
```

> Of course --data implies POST so you don't have to also specify the --request flag

```
curl --user "caspyin" --data '{"description":"Created via API","public":"true","files":{"file1.txt":{"content":"Demo"}}' https://api.github.com/gists
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i got it. I just used the wrong url. This is what I did

```
curl --user "{user}:{password}" -X POST -d '{"name":"api-test","description":"made with github api","private":"true","homepage":"https://github.com"}' \\ https://api.github.com/user/repos // <- IMPORTANT PART
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I mention in my answer, plus the fact you used POST without the -X.